# Multiple tables with same POCO class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have an existing database where I have four identical and unrelated tables.

I want to use the same POCO class to describe all four without having to create duplicates of the same class.

This is what my context looks like so far:

```
class StatsContext : DbContext
{
    // [MagicTableAttribute( "map_ratings_vsh" )] -- does something like this exist?
    public DbSet<MapRatings> MapRatingsVSH { get; set; }

    public DbSet<MapRatings> MapRatingsJump { get; set; }

    // 2 more tables using same class
}

class MapRatings
{
    public string SteamID { get; set; }

    public string Map { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }

    [Column( "rated" )]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that the existing tables are named "map_ratings_vsh" and "map_ratings_jump", and I cannot use the data annotations `TableAttribute` because it can only be used on the class.

Is there some other way--maybe the fluent api--to describe my schema?

Comment: Typically, one would only have a single table, and then use a discriminator column to decided which entities are of each type.  Why don't you want to do this?

Comment: @MystereMan, I completely agree, but I'm forced to use this existing schema.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way I've found to solve this is to use inheritance.

```
[Table("map_ratings_vsh")]
public class MapRatingsVSH : MapRatingsBase {}

[Table("map_ratings_jump")]
public class MapRatingsJump : MapRatingsBase {}

public class MapRatingsBase
{
    public string SteamID { get; set; }

    public string Map { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }

    [Column( "rated" )]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can have your DbContext look like:

```
public class StatsContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<MapRatingsVSH> MapRatingsVSH { get; set; }

    public DbSet<MapRatingsJump> MapRatingsJump { get; set; }

}
```

EF shouldn't have any problem understanding that these are two different tables even though the implementation will be in the same place (`MapRatingsBase`)

Comment: This is what I ended up going with, so I'll accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fluent api to map some properties to one table and other properties to another table like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TestResult>()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.Properties(t => new { /* map_ratings_vsh columns */ });
        m.ToTable("map_ratings_vsh");
    })
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.Properties(t => new { /* map_ratings_jump columns */ });
        m.ToTable("map_ratings_jump");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The (hacky) way I've handled this in the past is to return data using a stored procedure or view, and then provide a "AddEntity" or "SaveEntity" method on the DbContext implementation that persists the entity in question